# How do I make an h1 element for each value in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array in JavaScript as shown in the example below. My question is: how can I have an h1 element for each value of the array when a button is clicked?

```js
Names = []

function submit() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
  Names.push(inputValue);
  let frame = document.getElementById("frame");
  frame.innerHTML = `<div><h1>${Names}</h1></div>`
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<input placeholder="name" id="name">
<div id="frame"></div>
```

How do I create separate H1 elements which contain each value from the array?

Comment: You could do this by iterating through your Names array. Have a look at [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below, by emptying the `frame` `innerHTML` every time you wish to add a new one and then iterating through the `Names` list and creating new `h1` elements using `document.createElement("h1")`. The key here is to use `append()` to add the created element to the desired element.

**Check below:**

```js
var Names = []

function submit() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
  Names.push(inputValue);
  let frame = document.getElementById("frame");
  
  frame.innerHTML = "";
  
  Names.forEach(function(el, i) {
    let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    h1.innerHTML = Names[i];
    frame.append(h1);
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<input placeholder="name" id="name">
<div id="frame"></div>
```

Another, and possibly better approach would be to just use `append()` to add the new input, like this:

```js
var Names = []

function submit() {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("name").value;
  Names.push(inputValue);
  let frame = document.getElementById("frame");
  let h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  h1.innerHTML = inputValue;
  frame.append(h1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<input placeholder="name" id="name">
<div id="frame"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean whenever the user enter a name
and press submit.. the name should be added to a list with id frame right?

If yes then you just need to fix alittle problem:

```
 frame.innerHTML = `<div><h1>${Names}</h1></div>`
```

this line of code is causing this issue, you are rewriting the new name on top of the old one, and what you should do is something like:

frame = old frame + new name

in code :

```
 frame.innerHTML += `<div><h1>${Names}</h1></div>`
```

or

```
 frame.innerHTML = frame.innerHTML+ `<div><h1>${Names}</h1></div>`
```

both lines of codes do the same thing but are written in a different way

Comment: It would be good if an h1 element is created for each element inside of the array..

Comment: yeah, i kind of ignore the fact that he was pushing the result into an array.. and it would be better if he loops through it and add the value to the frame div.. that was my bad